# VBA - Filling a cell value after a combobox text is entered/changed

Tags: vba, events, combobox, excel-2010

I have the following piece of code on my workbook on my sheet, which is intended to test intersection using ws change and then go to the combo box and retrieve whatever value is entered in the box. However, what is happening is that after the value is entered in the combo box the first time the cell isn't updating with it's value. I have to click it again, and then it will populate. I know I have to likely use another event procedure, but I have no clue about combo box events. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thx Mike.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim aRng As Range
Dim tRng As Range

Set aRng = Range("C19:C36")
Set tRng = Sheet2.Range("I2")

Application.EnableEvents = False  'to prevent re-iteration of event

On Error GoTo cleanup:
If Not Intersect(aRng, Target) Is Nothing Then
Call Sheet2.ComboBox1_Change
Target.Value = Sheet2.ComboBox1.Value
End If

cleanup:            'enable events once again
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

and on Sheet 2 where the box is.

```
Public Sub ComboBox1_Change()
With ComboBox1
.Activate
.SelText = Empty
.DropDown
.MatchRequired = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: is this about Excel ? Tag your question with the product!

Comment: Done. MS Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

To get to the basics of your question, the Combobox has a LinkedCell property. If you enter the cell address on Sheet1 there, the selected item in the ComboBox will be displayed on Sheet1. (If a value is entered in that Cell on Sheet1, it will also be displayed in the ComboBox.)

[ComboBox LinkedCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpdjW.jpg)

You can force Sheet1 to be displayed after a selection is made in the ComboBox with this code (in the module of Sheet2):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Sheet1.Select
End Sub
```

Using Worksheet_Change will only have effect AFTER something has been entered into the cell (and RETURN has been hit).

Comment: So would you suggest that I re-structure the flow of the code?

Comment: Indeed, start with setting up the example I gave, then add extras.